# SignalR causing null reference exception while adding custom dialog services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr

We are trying to add custom services with SignalR, but it throws a null exception when we invoke the custom services. If we specify the component tag in mainLayout.razor like <BlazorApp3.DialogForms.Test/>, it is unable to run the project.

Sample: https://uploadnow.io/f/Y59l8d9

[image]
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eryj5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GeRc.png)

Are we missing any configuration in the attached sample?

Need to run the signalR with custom dialog service sample without any exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please provide code samples that re-create the problem, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `DialogService` class like below and the issue could be fixed.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp3.DialogForms
{
    public class DialogService
    {
        private event Action<DialogOptions> dialogInstance;

        public event Action<DialogOptions> DialogInstance
        {
            add => dialogInstance += value;
            remove => dialogInstance -= value;
        }
        public async Task Open(DialogOptions options)
        {
            // Invoke Test to update and show the dialog with options
            this.dialogInstance?.Invoke(options);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is still not working.

Comment: @PriyankaKarthikeyan Could you share more error details?

Comment: The above solution handled the null exception, but I am facing an issue with running this sample.   https://uploadnow.io/f/cy8kJSy

Comment: Hi @PriyankaKarthikeyan, you are facing stackoverflowExceptions, right ?  The names of your model and razor page are both `Test`, which encounters an ambiguity at runtime, please modify the name to solve the problem.